# should a property be attributed as retain if it's returned from calling a C method by reference

Tags: objective-c, properties, return-by-reference

For the following code (build without ARC)

in .h

```
@interface VideoFrameExtractor : NSObject {
AVFormatContext *pFormatCtx;
AVCodecContext *pCodecCtx;
}
```

in .m

```
int av_open_input_file(AVFormatContext **ic_ptr, const char *filename,
                       AVInputFormat *fmt,
                       int buf_size,
                       AVFormatParameters *ap);

    // Open video file
    if(av_open_input_file(&pFormatCtx, [moviePath  cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding], NULL, 0, NULL)!=0)
        goto initError; // Couldn't open file

    // Retrieve stream information
    if(av_find_stream_info(pFormatCtx)<0)
        goto initError; // Couldn't find stream information
```

Should we set the attribute for the pFormatCtx property to be retain or something else? The reason asking this is that we got EXC_BAD_ACCESS error on referencing the property in the av_find_stream_info call.

Comment: are av_open_input_file and av_find_stream_info from ffmpeg?

Comment: yes, just build the ffmpeg using llvm-gcc, and try running the iFrameExtractor app (using ffmpeg) on iPhone simulator. hit the issue immediately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should we set the attribute for the pFormatCtx property to be strong or something else?

`av_open_input_file` is not an Objective C method, and it allocates memory directly outside of ARC and without any kind of reference counting. So you definitely do not need handling those references through strong properties.

You should definitely look for it in the the way `av_find_stream_info` may fail.

Actually, what I see is that you should follow some steps to correctly setup your library to work:

```
AVFormatContext* pFormatCtx = avformat_alloc_context();
avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, filename, NULL, NULL);
int64_t duration = pFormatCtx->duration;
// etc
avformat_free_context(pFormatCtx);
```

In any case, inspect the documentation and also have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.inb.uni-luebeck.de/~boehme/using_libavcodec.html).

Comment: that's good to know. the S.O post used std library in the sample code snippet. how can I do that w/o std library?

Comment: actually, that post referred to a different scenario (reading av data from memory and not disk), so I removed its reference. That also explains the use of streams and std, but this is definitely not required. I am adding some more hints to my answer right now...

Comment: I added the line to do the avformat_alloc_context, but it's still hitting the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. could it be memory alignment problem? EXC_BAD_ACCESS meant to say that the pFormatCtx, when called by av_find_stream_info, has been garbaged/released. wondering why?